# C++ Naming Conventions for C# Developers

Tags: c#, c++, variables, naming-conventions, conventions

C# has a tool called [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) written by Microsoft which gives you some default rules that I find very useful to end any bickering among teams about code style. The default rules state that all class variables must use the following syntax to refer to class variables:

```
this.classVariable  // C# Default StyleCop Naming Convention
```

The main alternative in C# is to use a leading underscore instead:

```
_classVariable      // C# Alternative StyleCop Naming Convention
```

C++ seems to have a large number of [naming restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) which rule out the leading underscore as this is reserved for libraries and operating systems. What about using the 'this' keyword like this, is this a common syntax?

```
this->classVariable // C++
```

I don't want this post to descend into a fight about style. **I am not asking your opinion on coding style**. I just want to know a short concise list of what the most common styles are and if the above example is used commonly, so I can pick one and move on.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure why this question was put on hold. Specific questions were asked and we got one very good answer. No opinion was expressed anywhere. Admittedly, this is a touchy subject but I think all went well in the end.

Comment: `this` is generally not used unless for clarity, anyway this question is off-topic as it will elicit opinions.

Comment: There are many contradicting conventions on C++ naming style.

Comment: I am not asking for opinions as stated in my question. I am asking a specific question about a C# coding style and if it can be translated to C++. I am also asking for a short list of styles and **no opinions**.

Comment: The answer is to get a copy of the Framework Design Guidelines.  It holds the "correct" way to "style" your code for C# developers.  A survey of users here is not as authoritative or as thorough as this document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 styles, as far as I know.

First, use underscore:

```
class Person
{
private:
    int _age;
    ...
```

You're worried about naming restrictions, but don't worry - first underscore + **non**-uppercase **on non-global names** is not illegal.

(first underscore + **uppercase** *is* illegal; you must not use names like this: `_Age`.)

Second, use `m_`. (`m` means member.)

```
class Person
{
private:
    int m_age;
    ...
```

This style is used in MFC, and I also prefer this.

Third, use underscore, on *the last part of name*.

```
class Person
{
private:
    int age_;
    ...
```

It isn't seen many times, but I've seen it before >o<

---

Well, you can also name your all class variable normally and use `this->`.

```
class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    ...
public:
    void SetAge(int age) { this->age = age; }
    ...
```

However, this isn't used widely; above all, it's so inconvenient. (Also I have hardly seen `this.var` style in C# except tool-generated source - is it really widely-used in C#??)

As you see, `this->` syntax is used to avoid such a ambiguous situation:

```
void Person::SetAge(int age)
{
    age = age; // what does it mean?
}
```

*(In addition, in the situation like this, `age` means the parameter; because it's more local than `Person::age`, so the local `age` hides `Person::age`.)*

But it isn't used widely as I said. In this situation, It's much better to edit the name of one of `age`s, than to use `this->`.

`this` pointer just means myself; like any other languages which has `class`, including C#, It is used like this:

```
void SomeUtilFunction(Person *pPerson);

void Person::Foo()
{
    ...
    SomeUtilFunction(this); // refer to myself
    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. exactly what I asked for. Have an up-vote. I'd still be interested to see if anyone has any info about the use of the 'this->' syntax.

Comment: @RehanSaeed please see edit >o<

Comment: Thanks. I have seen the 'this' keyword more often of late. Probably due to take up of the StyleCop tool which uses it as the default style. I switched from underscores to 'this' in C#. There are advantages and disadvantages to both, just a matter of preference. Coming from C# 'this->' just looked easier on my eye, so that is the only reason I asked. I think I'll stick with underscores in C++.